# Is there a way to multiply two columns in R like this, ex. 17.5 x 4 would give me a list of 4 rows 17.5,17.5,17.5,17.5?

Tags: r

I need to multiply two columns so that the result, columnC, is a list of columnA with columnB entries (sorry if that is confusing I dont know how else to say it). So columnA (17.5) * columnB (4) gives columnC (17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5).
Is this possible? I need to make a histogram in R but the data is entered in the A B format (i.e. there were 4 ind at 17.5, 2 ind at 16.8, 5 ind at 15.9, etc) but I cannot get the plotting to work this way so I thought if I changed it to just a list of values it would work. It is a very large data set and doing this manually is prohibitive. Is there a better way to do this? New to R so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could try `rep(dat$a, dat$b)`, or if you want it in the dataframe: `dat$c = apply(dat, 1, function(x) rep(x['a'], x['b']))`

Comment: thanks for the answer but Im still confused. what function should I use to make it do what I want? and it keeps telling me I have an invalid time argument?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example (use `dput`)

Comment: You want me to upload the whole data set? I haven't written any code that works, I was just trying to figure out what jeremycg posted earlier. Is there a function that can do what I want? It seems like it should be simple but Im new to R and not very good at this.

Comment: No. Not the whole dataset :) Just a sample (`dput(head(df, 5))`)

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g38249432d6bbf8f89998317459ee0166577ed7f56

Comment: well thats probably more than you need, but only a fraction of the whole set

Comment: I can't open that (work restrictions) but I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the following code will do what you want it to:

```
dat <- data.frame( x = c(17.5,16.8,15.9),y=c(4,2,5))
newDat <- data.frame( x = rep(dat$x,dat$y), y = rep(1,sum(dat$y) ) )

if(!require("ggplot2")){ #INCLUDE PACKAGE ggplot2 AND INSTALL IT IF IT'S NOT ALREADY INSTALLED
    install.packages("ggplot2",repos="http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/",dependencies = TRUE)
    library("ggplot2")
}

ggplot(newDat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(x))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Depending on the size of your data this might not make sense and you might want to do something other than appending a column of 1 to your dataframe, but for this toy example it functions fine. You should get something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data frame (called df) is as follows:

```
     A B
1 17.5 5
2 16.8 8
```

One way to expand (i.e. replicate) is

```
df <- df[rep(rownames(df), df$B),]
#       A B
#1   17.5 5
#1.1 17.5 5
#1.2 17.5 5
#1.3 17.5 5
#1.4 17.5 5
#2   16.8 8
#2.1 16.8 8
#2.2 16.8 8
#2.3 16.8 8
#2.4 16.8 8
#2.5 16.8 8
#2.6 16.8 8
#2.7 16.8 8
```

If you want to 'tidy' your rownames you can just do,

```
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

Comment: It says invalid "times" argument, I am assuming bc of some of the NA values, how do i get it to ignore them? Thanks for the help so far, I almost got it.

Comment: I assume the NAs are in your columnB, so you could do `df[is.na(df)] <- 1`

Comment: That works perfect. I set it to 0 instead of 1 bc it means there are no individuals at that temperature, and it works great. One last thing that I can probably figure out, I have only one column of temperatures, columnA, and many columns of data related it to it, B-J, so right now the only way I know how to do this is to do what we did above 8 times and then combine those new columns into one data frame. Smarter way to to do this? Thanks again for all the help!!